# Unit tests organisation - how not to run base class tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have tests like this:

```
import unittest

class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

   def setUp(self):
      self.decorator = None

   def testA(self):
      data = someGeneratorA().generate()
      self.assertTrue(self.decorator.someAction(data))  

   def testB(self):
      data = someGeneratorB().generate()
      self.assertTrue(self.decorator.someAction(data))  

   def testC(self):
      data = someGeneratorC().generate()
      self.assertTrue(self.decorator.someAction(data))  


class TestCaseA(TestBase):

   def setUp(self):
      self.decorator = SomeDecoratorA


class TestCaseB(TestBase):

   def setUp(self):
      self.decorator = SomeDecoratorB
```

As you see, **TestCaseA** and **TestCaseB** is very similar, so I made **TestBase** class which implement body of *testA*, *testB* and *testC* method.

TestCaseA different from TestCaseB only decorator parameter.

So, I would like to ask, is any better way to organize my tests? And I have problem beacuse TestBase class - it's test's - shouldn't be runned ever (*self.decorator* is None so it will rase an exception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that inherits from `unittest.TestCase` is seen as a set of tests.

You could instead have your base class *not* inherit from `TestCase`, moving that base class to your concrete test classes instead:

```
class TestBase(object):
    # base tests to be reused

class TestCaseA(TestBase, unittest.TestCase):
    # Concrete tests, reusing tests defined on TestBase

class TestCaseB(TestBase, unittest.TestCase):
    # Concrete tests, reusing tests defined on TestBase
```